# Mix 3 Lists, Each List 35 Elements Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 lists like

```
_1st = ["Qa4AJ-","Qb4AJ-","Qc4AJ-","Qd4AJ-","Qe4AJ-","Qf4AJ-","Qg4AJ-","Qh4AJ-","Qi4AJ-","QJ4AJ-","Qk4AJ-","Ql4AJ-","Qm4AJ-","Qn4AJ-","Qo4AJ-","Qp4AJ-","Qq4AJ-","Qr4AJ-","Qs4AJ-","Qt4AJ-","Qu4AJ-","Qv4AJ-","Qw4AJ-","Qx4AJ-","Qy4AJ-","Qz4AJ-","Q14AJ-","Q24AJ-","Q34AJ-","Q44AJ-","Q54AJ-","Q64AJ-","Q74AJ-","Q84AJ-","Q94AJ-"]
_2nd = ["H581A-","H582A-","H583A-","H584A-","H585A-","H586A-","H587A-","H588A-","H589A-","H58aA-","H58bA-","H58cA-","H58dA-","H58eA-","H58fA-","H58gA-","H58hA-","H58iA-","H58jA-","H58kA-","H58lA-","H58mA-","H58nA-","H58oA-","H58pA-","H58qA-","H58rA-","H58sA-","H58tA-","H58uA-","H58vA-","H58wA-","H58xA-","H58yA-","H58zA-"]
_3rd = ["KNaQ3","KNbQ3","KNcQ3","KNdQ3","KNeQ3","KNfQ3","KNgQ3","KNhQ3","KNiQ3","KNjQ3","KNkQ3","KNlQ3","KNmQ3","KNnQ3","KNoQ3","KNpQ3","KNqQ3","KNrQ3","KNsQ3","KNtQ3","KNuQ3","KNvQ3","KNwQ3","KNxQ3","KNyQ3","KNzQ3","KN1Q3","KN2Q3","KN3Q3","KN4Q3","KN5Q3","KN6Q3","KN7Q3","KN8Q3","KN9Q3"]
```

I want to mix them together
For example, I want Python print 1st element of _1st with 1st element of _2nd and 1st element of _3rd
and then print 1st element of _1st with 1st element of _2nd and 2nd element of _3rd.
I need it to mix every single element from every list to other elements from other lists

I have no Idea "How I can do it".

I'm not sure if I clearly said what I want, but I hope u get it.

Comment: Are you looking for the product?  `list(product(zip(_1st, _2nd, _3rd)))`

Comment: @JackEvans: you forgot to mention that it is [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're looking for is the 'cartesian product' of these lists

In Python 2.6+

```
import itertools
for element in itertools.product(_1st, _2nd, _3rd):
    print(element)
```